# What is SOA, Microservices, REST and Web Services "in plain English"?

Tags: web-services, rest, soa, microservices

Could somebody explain SOA, Microservices, REST and Web Services in simple terms. It is really fascinating and confusing me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

**SOA** (Service oriented architecture) as the name suggests that it is combination of services. These services are loosly coupled and interacts with each
other to provide a solution. Services may be RESTful web service to carry out some function.

**Microservices** - Again as the name suggests micro services. The idea behind microservices is that it becomes easier to build and maintain some type of services when they are broken down into smaller, composable pieces that work together.

**Webservices** - A service (some functionality like checking seat availability in a train) available on web is known as web service. Such services communicate over the WWW using HTTP.

**REST** - It is just an architectural style for designing webservices.

We can think like this:- SOA is having some services. These services are combination of microservices. Those microservices are exposed as webservices and the webservices are build on REST.

Answer (score 3):

**SOA**

Building software out of widgets.

**Microservices**

Building software out of small widgets.

**Web Services**

Makes widgets look like the internet

**REST**

Makes widgets look a lot like the internet

Comment: This seems to be a good answer but could you explain in a little elaborated fashion with some real world example as I am new to this buzzword?

Comment: @Prajwal - books have been written about each of these subjects. I could certainly elaborate a little, and I will once I have a little time. I'll message you once I have done so.